# What is the difference between ScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd() and ScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom()?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

Does anyone know what is the difference between ScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd() and ScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom()?

In Visual Studio 2022, the description of ScrollToEnd() and ScrollToBottom() is the same:
"Scrolls vertically to the end of ScrollViewer content."

Nevertheless, there must be a difference, otherwise there would not exist both.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoend?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Remarks

This method scrolls to both the vertical and horizontal end points of the content.

Comment: ScrollToBottom only scrolls vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScrollToBottom()` scrolls to the bottommost Y coordinate, but does not change the horizontal offset. Thus this method only changes the current Y offset.

`ScrollToEnd()` scrolls to both the bottommost Y coordinate AND the rightmost X coordinate. Thus this method changes both the current Y AND the current X coordinates.

Note that in many cases like this, if you're unsure what the code does you can look at the implementation on https://source.dot.net/

For this particular case: https://source.dot.net/#PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/ScrollViewer.cs,488ab4a977a015eb

However, the documentation does actually specify the behaviour for these methods:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoend?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

The naming of those two methods is not great. It might have been better to call them `ScrollToBottom()` and `ScrollToBottomRight()` and then it would have been more obvious (IMO).